# Why Isn't A Table View Detecting The Right Height For A Cell?

Tags: ios5, xcode4, uitableview, uikit, uistoryboard

Basically, I have a UITabBar that contains a UITableView in each tab. The tables are different, but they have the same custom UITableViewCells, except that the second table view has a label in bold font.

Here's an screenshot to explain this better:

[image: Screenshot]

You can clearly cell the UITabBar, and the UITableViews it contains.
You can observe that the cells are almost the same except for the bolded font. I created the second UITableViewCell by option-dragging the first one and changing the font of the first label. It's literally an exact copy of the other cell, with a different label and a different identifier.

But when I run my app, I see two different things. Only the cells from the first table view look fine. The ones from the second look like normal cells without any custom views inside.

Here is a screenshot of the first table view that looks fine:

[image: Correct Table View Cell]

But the second that should show exactly the same cells with the same sizes does not.

[image: Incorrect Table View Cell]

So what gives? What's going on? This makes no sense. The TableViewCells are exactly the same with the few variations I mentioned above. Yes, they also have different view controllers, but I haven't touched any of the view controllers for the first cell to look fine.

Could it be an XCode bug? Honestly I find XCode to be very buggy, so I wouldn't be surprised if for some reason it was completely ignoring my second cell.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my own stupidity. I was modifying the wrong screen all that time. Late answer, solved it years ago, but I think this should help those check "the little things", always.